# Agreggate sum and averaga keeping columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that has integer values and percentages, as you can see in m paste below, some of the percentage values are NaN.

```
            total  sent  delivered  opens   open_rate  click_rate  click_to_open_rate
2018-06-20      1     0          0      0         NaN         NaN                 NaN
2018-06-22      1     1          0      0         0.5         NaN                 NaN
2018-06-25      1     1          0      0         0.5         1.0                 NaN
2018-07-02      2     2          1      0         0.0         0.0                 NaN
```

I need a way to aggregate this data keeping the column names and adding up integer values (columns `total, send, delivered, opens`) and averaging percentage columns (`open_rate, click_rate, click_to_open_rate`)

If I simply do `df.sum()` or `df.agg('sum')` I will get data with no column names, since I'm later dumping this to a dictionary with `to_dict`.

I'm expecting to get:

```
{
    total:                 5,
    sent:                  4,
    delivered:             1,
    opens:                 0,
    open_rate:             0.25,
    click_rate:            0.25,
    click_to_open_rate:    0.0
}
```

Comment: `df.sum()` and `df.mean()` return exactly what you want.. Can you post the output of `df.sum()` and the expected output?

Comment: @RafaelC: I updated the question with what I expect to get. Notice that some columns need to get the average, while other the sum.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is what you want, the trick is to put your aggregate function(s) inside `[]`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(-1, 3), columns=list('abc'))

print(df.agg([sum]))
#      a   b   c
# sum  30  35  40

print(df.agg([sum, np.mean]))
#          a     b     c
# sum   30.0  35.0  40.0
# mean   6.0   7.0   8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need,

```
sum_columns=['total','sent','delivered','opens']
mean_columns=['open_rate','click_rate','click_to_open_rate']
output=df[sum_columns].sum().append(df[mean_columns].fillna(0).mean()).to_dict()
print(output)
{ 
 'click_rate': 0.25,
 'click_to_open_rate': 0.0,
 'delivered': 1.0,
 'open_rate': 0.25,
 'opens': 0.0,
 'sent': 4.0,
 'total': 5.0
}
```